# AspNetCacheProfile attribute in inner method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I have an api method that gets a lot of data in the application start up.
90% of the data is relevant for all application users and the other 10% need to be changed by the user id and his environment and app version.
To avoid calling the first method every time user connect and make the start up slower,
i added : AspNetCacheProfile attribute.
But in this situation i can`t use the user id, environment and version at this method
because it is the data of the first user called the method.

So,
I added new method (the second one) and set the  AspNetCacheProfile attribute above it
and called this method from the first one.
This way i can cache the general data and update the other 10% each call.

I just wanted to know .. will it work ? 
I was not sure because the second method is not called directly, it is called from the first one.

```
           [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetData")]
           public APIResponse GetData()
           {
                try
                {
                    MyCachedResponse = GetMyCachedResponse();

                    foreach (var info in data.info)
                    {
                        if (Something)
                        { 
                           // Update some specific values inside
                        }               
                    }

                    AppState.CurrentResponse.Data = data;
                }

                return AppState.CurrentResponse;
            }

            [AspNetCacheProfile("OneMinuteCaching")]
            private MyCachedResponse GetMyCachedResponse()
            {
                return new MyCachedResponse(categories);
            }
```